# How to get Bandwidth allocated to a port on which my application running?

Tags: c#

My application(WIN app C#.net) is running on port "1001" and the port allocated bandwidth of 10MB.
My requirement is how do i get bandwidth of a port 1001 on which my app is running programatically?

After i get the bandwidth , i want allocate 70% of bandwidth to my application and rest i want to allocate to other application?
How can i?

Comment: You have to keep track of what you send / receive over your Socket, and implement whatever logic you wish.

Comment: What do you mean by 10MB ? megabytes or megabit/s, if you want to throttle the bandwidth, look into `ThrottledStream`

Comment: This doesn't exist, all applications (ports) share the network connection.  Much like a cpu, if you run four programs on a single core cpu and they run full bore then they'll each get 25% of the cpu.  Same for a network.